# Why is my ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist "damaged"?

Tags: finder, safari, filevault, bookmarks

I'm trying to edit my Safari bookmarks programmatically. When I try to open the file `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist`, I get an pop-up with the error:

> “Bookmarks.plist” is damaged and can’t be opened. You should move it to the Trash.

If I try to preview it by pressing space, it shows thousands of lines of this kind of nonsensical content:

[image: Preview of the file]

Despite of this my Safari bookmarks are working normally though.

I am using FileVault, but shouldn't all the files be unencrypted when the computer is open?

Comment: I wonder if it is a binary plist file? PLUTIL is a command line tool to "decode" such files and running that file through it might yield better results. Just spitballin' here...

Comment: @Steve Chambers, Yes the `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist` file is a binary file; however' it does not need to be converted if using the right tools. The OP has not presented any details of how he programmatically edited it. Hopefully he made a backup before editing it and should just restore from the backup.

Comment: The file is not encrypted, it is just not plain text. You can most likely open the file with BBEdit, for example. However, editing the Bookmarks.plist file is probably not going to work the way that you want, so it would be useful to know what you are trying to accomplish before we go much further.

Comment: @user3339894 I have not edited the file yet at all. It just was that way.

Comment: @TJLuoma This question is what I'm trying to accomplish: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56517403/how-to-create-and-manage-macos-safari-bookmarks-programmatically

Comment: I think you’ll find this impossible with the way MacOS manages Safari bookmarks (I’m assuming the bookmarks are synced via iCloud). I did some experimentation with restoring a backup of my plist and found that it did not work at all. The only reliable way I found was using the Export Bookmarks item which generates an html file. I could import that. Moral of the story: don’t try mucking with the plist directly. macOS does not like that and will actively work against all your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

Mine bookmarks preview looks the same as yours; in finder or from terminal you do not have the rights to do something with. However, with `Safari | Bookmarks | Edit Bookmarks` you can do anything you need with it - deleting an item, renaming, modifying the address. If you need to export it, you can do it from `File | Export Bookmarks...` - and will be exported as .html (while you are in Edit page).